# Show error when normal user try to login in CP

Tags: craft3, login

when I login to my Craft CMS website via a normal user that user doesn't have permission to login to the Control Panel, it displays some error like `HTTP 403 – Forbidden – yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException`.

This error is correct but I want to display some message instead of this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this because you have `'devMode' => true,` in your `config/general` try switching to `false` and should hit a 'user friendly' message

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: but can you explain me what actually happening there

Comment: @dyanmicDreamz This should help: https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does